# Folder cleanup with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'd like to clean up some directories after my script runs by deleting certain folders and files from the current directory if they exist. Originally, I structured the script like this:

```
if (Test-Path Folder1) {
  Remove-Item -r Folder1
}
if (Test-Path Folder2) {
  Remove-Item -r Folder2
}
if (Test-Path File1) {
  Remove-Item File1
}
```

Now that I have quite a few items listed in this section, I'd like to clean up the code. How can I do so?

Side note: The items are cleaned up *before* the script runs, since they are left over from the previous run in case I need to examine them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
# if you want to avoid errors on missed paths
# (because even ignored errors are added to $Error)
# (or you want to -ErrorAction Stop if an item is not removed)
@(
    'Directory1'
    'Directory2'
    'File1'
) |
Where-Object { Test-Path $_ } |
ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop }
```

Comment: You can pipe straight into `Remove-Item` by dropping the `$_`.

Comment: Good point (for binding input to the -Path parameter). In fact, I usually use -LiteralPath as much as possible (less error prone), so I proposed this version still keeping -LiteralPath in mind.

Comment: Great snippet, I've been struggling with "Error: directory is not empty" for longer than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 1):

```
Folder1, Folder2, File1, Folder3 |
    ?{ test-path $_ } |
        %{
            if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
                rm -rec $_ #  For directories, do the delete recursively
            } else {
                rm $_ #  for files, just delete the item
            }
        }
```

Or, you could do two separate blocks for each type.

```
Folder1, Folder2, File1, Folder3 |
    ?{ test-path $_ } |
        ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
            rm -rec

Folder1, Folder2, File1, Folder3 |
    ?{ test-path $_ } |
        ?{ -not ($_.PSIsContainer) } |
            rm
```

Comment: It turns out `Remove-Item -r` works for both folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility

```
function ql {$args}

ql Folder1 Folder2 Folder3 File3 |
    ForEach {
        if(Test-Path $_) {
            Remove-Item $_
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you do not mind to have a few ignored errors
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction 0 @(
    'Directory1'
    'Directory2'
    'File1'
)
```

Comment: I prefer to not have ignored errors since they are pretty easily avoided here. :)

Comment: Agree, it is not suitable for your scenario because you should know the issues before the script continues. Still, this version will do in some other cases, for example cleanup *after* the script work.